# List use of : vs. ::

Tags: python, numpy

Basic question, but what is the difference between the two things below:

```
list[0::,5]
list[0:,5]
```

Also, which one (if either) references 1 element vs. multiple?

Comment: Neither syntax is recognized by the default Python `list` type; are you talking about NumPy `array`s here? I've added the `numpy` tag for you, feel free to remove it again (but do expand your question to add detail, it is not clear what you are asking then).

Comment: For your second question, you could just try it.

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html and play with it in the interpreter...

Comment: Yep I meant NumPy's array! My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent, but I'm going to call them `arr` instead since presumably for a numpy array.

```
arr[0::,5]
arr[0:,5]
```

They're also equivalent to

```
arr[:, 5]
```

The `:` notation in a slice is given as

```
arr[start:end:step]
```

For the rows.  After the comma, it's the same for columns (and so on for more dimensions).

If you leave of the specifiers any out, they are assumed to be:

```
arr[0:len(arr):1]
```

So, if you leave them all blank and keep the separators, you have:

```
arr[::]
```

Of course, you can insert any default and it'll still be the same:

```
arr[0::]
arr[:len(arr):]
arr[::1]
```

You only need to put the separators to remove ambiguity.  To imply the `step` size, you have to have both separators:

```
arr[::1]
```

But to imply the `end`, you only need one:

```
arr[:end]
```

However, if you have no separators, that's just getting an item, not a slice, so the first separator is necessary:

```
arr[0]  # only the first item!
arr[0:] # all items
```

Comment: Good and complete answer. Nevertheless, maybe you want to point out that the equivalences and defaults indeed hold for numpy arrays, but not necessarily for other objects that implement `__getitem__`. ([0::,5] indeed is the same as [0:,5], but [:,5] is not).

Comment: True, as you mentioned in your answer :)  I'll leave the warning in your comment as sufficient, given my assumption of the OP's familiarity with slice objects.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples pass `(slice(0, None, None), 5)` to the `__getitem__` function of `list` (your variable called `list`). There is no difference. Your question can be simplified to:

Is `a[0::]` the same as `a[0:]`, and the answer is still "yes".

On the other hand side, `a[:0]` is not the same as `a[::0]`, nor is `a[0:0]` the same as `a[0::0]`.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class A:
    def __getitem__ (self, item):
        print (item)


a = A ()
a [0::,5] #passes a tuple
a [0:,5] #passes a tuple

a [0:] #passes a slice
a [0::]
a [:0]
a [::0]
a [0:0]
a [0::0]

print ('Askewchan\'s conjecture:')
a [:]
a [0:]
```

Now the return value of `__getitem__` called with a tuple, depends on the implementation of the object on which it is called.

Comment: Also _effecively_ equivalent to `a[:]`, since the `0` is as implied as the others.

Comment: @askewchan this depends on the implementation of the object. Not necessarily `slice(0,None,None)` must yield the same value as `slice(None,None,None)`. Nevertheless, true enough for builtin iterables like lists.